# What does "Usual affair" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Woman changes Patrick's identity for his safety:

> Patrick: Patrick? I'm a Brit, not a Mick.
>
> Woman: So, your mom's Irish. **Usual affair**. This time, you're Patrick
> Hill from Lewisham.

What does "Usual affair" mean in this context?

Comment: We have no freaking clue what it means because you didn't provide enough context. Perhaps it means the woman stereotypes Irish women as having affairs a lot. Perhaps "Patrick" is used to changing his identity and this is a usual event for him. Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to guess because you provide virtually no context.

My best guess is that the man’s true name is neither Michael nor Patrick, but that he is truly English.

“Mick” is a common, but somewhat demeaning, term for someone who is Irish. Patrick is a common first name among Irish Catholics.

So it is plausible that the man is pointing out that his accent and name are slightly inconsistent in terms of a disguise.

As for the woman’s response under that supposition, she dismisses his objection with the observation that there are many reasons a name common among Irish Catholics may belong to someone with a British accent. Then she implies that he is used to using a false name, and this time his false identity is …

These are guesses. Next time, please give more context.

Comment: The dialogue is from the newly-released movie **Wrath of Man** and the scenario is exactly as Jeff Morrow supposes.   https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2021/05/25/wrath-of-man-transcript/